# php - put contents in directory

Tags: php, file-upload, file-put-contents

I am trying to upload an image in a server. The code I have works however, it saves the file in the root directory.

How can I make it upload the file inside '/resources/thumb/file.png' ?

```
<?php

$fileData = file_get_contents('php://input');

$fileName = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])", '', $_GET["fileName"]);

file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);

?>
```

Comment: `'/resources/thumb/' . $filename`? your path is just a string. if you want your file to go in some other location, YOU have to specify that location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you can write into the directory you has chosen.
And... use an absolute path to make sure we are writing were we wanted.

```
$your_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/resources/";
```

Then...

```
file_put_contents($your_path . $fileName, $fileData);
```

Comment: I have tried a lot using that code but its not uploading the file

Comment: Have you set permissions for php to write on /resources/thumb/ ? checked you error log?

Comment: yep i have setup as 777

Comment: I get the error: file_put_contents(/resources/165230.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/apps/Videos/uploadVideo.php on line 12

Comment: it seems that you are trying to write to /resources and the directory does not exist.

Comment: I would suggest using multitail for checking you logs https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/